# What is the right way to modify a global list using a function which takes the list as an argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a function which takes a list of numbers and modifies it by replacing the numbers with their squares. I have tried 4 different ways of iterating over a list and got 2 different kinds of results. Below is the code

```
nums = [1,2,3]

def square1(nums):
    nums = [i*i for i in nums]

def square2(nums):
    temp = list()
    for i in nums:
        temp.append(i*i)
    nums = temp

def square3(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        nums[i] = nums[i] * nums[i]

def square4(nums):
    i = 0
    while i < len(nums):
        nums[i] = nums[i] * nums[i]
        i += 1

square1(nums)
print(nums)
# Prints [1, 2, 3]

square2(nums)
print(nums)
# Prints [1, 2, 3]

square3(nums)
print(nums)
# Prints [1, 4, 9]

square4(nums)
print(nums)
# Prints [1, 16, 81]
```

Why is there a difference between the first 2 functions and the last 2? The `square1` and `square2` functions are unable to modify the global list whereas the `square3` and `square4` could modify. What is this behavior?

Comment: If it is global, you don't need to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: In first two func you are creating new list. While in last two you are updating the same list

Comment: `square3` and `square4` are explicitly writing into the list they are given. `square1` and `square2` are creating new lists and assigning them to local variables (because you didn't use the `global` keyword).

Comment: Don't use global variables. Use `return` to well, return the result from the function.

Comment: You could also "fix" `square1` by doing `nums[:] = `, i.e. replacing all the elements in the list without assigning a new list to the variable itself..

Comment: @khelwood Thanks, that clears the confusion I had.

Comment: Also note that even if you use `global nums` and then `nums = ...`, you are not modifying the list, but assign a _new_ list to the global variable, which is not entirely the same.

Comment: I can only re-iterate what others have said before: don't do this. Modifying data inside a function is a really bad pattern, as it will lead to subtle and hard to find bugs. Always (ok, *mostly*) compute *new* lists/data-structures and let the caller decide what to do with them.

Comment: This is generally considered a bad practice, but the differences are straight-forward, in the first you create new lists (and then don't do anything else with them so they get garbage collected as soon as the function returns), in the latter two, you mutate the lists directly (again, a bad practice)

Answer (score 1):

You pass the parameter as reference to the list
.
In `square1` you are using list comprehension it is creating the list for you on function local scope. And assinged the name `nums` to it.

In `square2` you created an empty list local to function scope and assigned just a name `nos` to it

In `square3` this explicit assignment changed at the reference it was pointing to `nums[i] = nums[i] * nums[i]`

In `square4` there is an assignment again. In first two you created new lists did not mutated the passed reference to list